# Cannot update table via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to update a row after a select

```
instance = session.query(Scouts).filter(Scouts.camp == camp, Scouts.user == user,Scouts.gender == gender).first()
instance.number_of_visits += 1
session.commit()
```

My Scouts class looks like:

```
class Scouts(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'scouts'
    camp = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    user = Column(Integer)
    gender = Column(String)
    number_of_visits = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, camp, user, gender, number_of_visits):
        self.camp = camp
        self.user = user
        self.gender = gender
        self.number_of_visits = number_of_visits
```

But I've got an error

```
UPDATE statement on table 'scouts' expected to update 1 row(s); 1001 were matched
```

where instance.number_of_visits equal to 1, it's not a list of rows or something like that.

Comment: Can there be more than one Scout per camp? If so, you cannot use `camp` as the primary key.

Comment: A primary key uniquely defines a row. If camp is not unique you will get the error you are getting. You should add a unique id field.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, for your review. the error was because of wrong column was primary key.