# why is sqlalchemy first() updating more than one record

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Ok I have some code like this

```
net = table1.query.filter_by(user='foo', size=size).first()
net.user = bar
net.commit()
```

I thought this would update one record, but much to my dismay it did not;
it updated ~2300
and generated this error

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.StaleDataError: UPDATE statement on table 'table1' expected to update 1 row(s); 2305 were matched
```

The docs say [`first()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html) applies a limit of one within the generated SQL.

The docs also say

> note this may consist of multiple result rows if join-loaded collections are present

but if I'm being honest I don't really understand that part.

Has anybody else had this issue? What function should I be using if not first?
Can anybody explain whats happening here, I'm real lost.

Comment: Please include both your model definition and your table schema as seen by the DB. I suspect you have defined something as the primary key in your model, which is not a key in the DB.

Comment: Here are some other Q/A that support that theory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824693/staledataerror-while-updating-a-row-in-a-table-with-error-expected-to-update, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796909/cannot-update-table-via-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, in my case problem was in model. I declared field as `primary_key=True` but the key was not really primary and should not even be unique. So `commit()` matched many rows.
Fix your model, I guess it will help